# RewriteRule only for specific pattern if 404 error would occur

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, http-status-code-404

I'm trying to update my .htaccess-file with the goal, that all pages that would have responded a "404 File not found"-error are rewritten to another url.

Example:
I've got those 3 links:

**404**: domain.com/category1/123-article-name.html

**working**: domain.com/static-page/10-ways-to-destroy-your-webpage.html

**untouched**: domain.com/simple-website.html

In this case the first link should be redirected to **domain.com/lost/123-article-name.html**,
the second one allready works. The third link should never be affected by my rule.

Hope you guys can help me. That's a really hard nut to crack, for me!
Thank you!

**EDIT:**

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/([0-9]+)-(.+).html$ lost/$2-$3.html [L]
```

This is what I've got so far, but this rule is kind of "stupid", because it does not test wheater the requested page exists or not.

Comment: does this page exists? `domain.com/lost/123-article-name.html` (with a dash in `article-name` instead of underscore) ?

Comment: Oh sorry, my fault. The Part after the "category" or "directory" is exactly the same when rewritten.

Comment: Can you go into more detail about what is happening with the link `domain.com/category1/123-article-name.html`, because it should rewrite properly.

Comment: This link should be redirected to domain.com/lost/123-article-name.html because a 404-error would occur (which also indicates, that this link is not reserved by another page).

Comment: Can you post your entire .htaccess file?

Comment: Here is my current .htaccess file: http://pastebin.com/AizDT0T3
With my rule (when it's working properly), I think, the big block can be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

Your rule and the rules for the CMS are mutually exclusive.

Line 41 (your rule) will only execute if the file exists, because if the file doesn't exist (rewriteConds on line 38 and 39) then the server tries to return `index.php?page=path_name` which will generate the 404 error.

If you know the names of the categories/directories that are missing, per lines 10 to 35, then you can apply your rule to the urls that have them in it.

```
RewriteRule ^(Ausbildung|Ausland|Berufswelt)/(?=.+-)(.+).html$ lost/$2.html
```

**Original Answer**

You can test to see if the file or directory exists by adding a rewrite condition

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f # True if the request isn't a file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d # True if the request isn't a directory
RewriteRule ^.*/([0-9]+)-(.+).html$ lost/$2-$3.html [L] 
#not I removed the first capture group because it is unnecessary.
```

**Side note:** In your example, because the `+` is greedy in the regex, the captured groups for domain.com/category1/123-article-name.html

- *123-article*
- *name*

Which works, but might be artificially constrain you.  You could change the rule to include a positive look ahead:

```
RewriteRule ^.*/(?=.+-)(.+).html$ lost/$1.html
```

The `(?=.+-)` tells the regex engine to create a match for any number of characters if it finds at least one `-`

You should check out this [htaccess test](http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/), it is awesome!

Comment: This works, but it also redirects (dynamically generated) pages, that have the same pattern as an article-page. I think because it's generated "on request", "-f" and "-d" does not work.

Comment: If I remove my above posted RewriteRule, yes.

Comment: I think you might need to attack this problem at the CMS level then, since we don't really have a way to check if the url leads to dynamic content or not.  What CMS are you using.